# I can't insert an image on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blob, mariadb

I'm trying to make an app with a form for posting a new post.

In this form, I have 4 parameters (the title, the description/tags, the full description and an image). When I receive the data from the app with my backend PHP API, I insert a row in my MySQL database.

Basically, I can insert the row with everything, except the image. Here is my code:

```
<?php
try
{
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=social;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
// $security = new White\Security;

$post = $_POST;
$file_tmp= $_FILES['img'];
$img = file_get_contents($file_tmp);
echo $img;
$title = addslashes($post['title']);
$description = addslashes($post['description']);
$fullDesc = addslashes($post['full']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, description, img, fullDesc, likes) VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$img', '$fullDesc', 0)";
echo $sql;
$db->exec($sql);
$status = array('status' => "success");
// header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Location: form.php");
```

and, here is my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly3gP.png

I searched on Google for something that would solve my problem, but I found nothing, so that's why I'm asking this question on this forum!

Comment: You really want put image into table? why not just upload and  then  save in  table only path to uploaded image ?

Comment: Have you tried to use prepared statments ?

Comment: @OTARIKI because, I have an unlimited DB, and only 15GB of disk.

Answer (score -1):

mysql_escape_string($img);
May be you can search in baidu when you found nothing..

Comment: Where does OP need to add this escape, and could you please provide a link to the documentation (and a description of what the escape does)? This answer is extremely short...

Comment: I'm using PHP 7, so no mysql extension

Answer (score -1):

Use pdo prepared statments.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

That will escape auto and save.